# Query on FQL table object_url doesn't work in V2.0

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try this query in Facebook's Tool FQL:

```
SELECT id FROM object_url WHERE url = 'https://www.facebook.com/fiorella.davide'
```

but tool doesn't function in V2.0, while tool functions in V1.0! Are there any problems for this query? I use PHP.

NOTE: For this information, there aren't specific permissions.

Comment: The `username` field has been deprecated in v2.0 – so it makes only sense that via FQL you are not able to look up the id for that profile URL containing a username any more.

Comment: I want user's id from url. How?

Comment: Not possible – one of the main _points_ of introducing API v2.0 was to protect user’s privacy better, and that’s why you only get app-scoped user ids and can’t make any use of their username any more.